# How to insert text before the first line of a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I've been looking around `sed` command to add text into a file in a specific line.
This works adding text after line 1:

```
sed '1 a\
```

But I want to add it *before* line 1. It would be:

```
sed '0 a\
```

but I get this error: `invalid usage of line address 0`.

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157659/add-text-to-file-at-certain-line-in-linux

Answer (score 218, accepted):

Use `sed`'s insert (`i`) option which will insert the text in the preceding line.

```
sed '1 i\
```

**Question author's update:**

To make it edit the file in place - with GNU `sed` - I had to add the
`-i` option:

```
sed -i '1 i\anything' file
```

Also syntax

```
sed  -i '1i text' filename
```

**For non-GNU sed**

You need to hit the return key immediately after the backslash `1i\` and after `first_line_text`:

```
sed -i '1i\
first_line_text
'
```

Also note that some non-GNU `sed` implementations (for example the one on macOS) *require* an argument for the `-i` flag (use `-i ''` to get the same effect as with GNU `sed`).

For `sed` implementations that does not support `-i` at all, run without this option but redirect the output to a new file.  Then replace the old file with the newly created file.

Comment: It doesn't work without `-i` option. I'll update your answer before accepting.

Comment: thanks. What OS are you using? Original solution worked on OpenSuse 9.

Comment: Linux Mint 13 Maya

Comment: Interesting! I'm on Lubuntu 13.10 and `sed '1 i\this text is entered above the existing first line' file` works for me.

Comment: Here, using `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2` just  `sed '1 i text to insert' -i file` worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: can confirm, gnu sed does not require the `-i` flag

Comment: Does not work on empty files.

Comment: The `-i` argument to `sed` tells it to edit the file in-place — I have a feeling all of the commenters here were seeing the same behavior, but simply had different expectations. Without `-i`, sed will execute the commands specified and _output_ the results to the terminal, unless you redirect it somewhere else. WITH `-i`, it will actually modify the file on disk, and write the changed version in place of the original. Two different approaches to `sed`-ing a file's contents, depending whether you need to preserve the unaltered version of the input file.

Comment: @rudimeier Huh! You're right, it doesn't work on _completely_ empty files. I guess because sed is super-literal, and you can't insert text at line 1 when there _isn't_ a "line 1" in the file. So `touch empty.txt && sed '1i Text' -i empty.txt` will do nothing, whereas `echo > blank.txt && sed '1i Text' -i blank.txt` will result in `blank.txt` containing a line that reads "Text", with a blank line after it.

Comment: @FeRD See my bad ranked `awk` answer below. This should work.

Comment: Well, inserting text into a completely empty file is kind of a pathological case, anyway. I can see how some script might need to be able to handle that case, but in any interactive use the way to "insert" text at the start of an empty file is just `echo "text" > file`. :-)

Comment: I get  "invalid command code f" with osx

Comment: Just added an update for OSX

Comment: How do you insert a string which needs to be processed first?

Comment: For macOS if you declare double quotes for some reason then you should declare \\ just before the new-line or text. for example: 
`sed -i '' "1i\\
"`

Comment: not sure what this command do, i just got `sed: 1: "~/testing.txt": extra characters at the end of q command`, definitely not a solution for the post title

Comment: For MacOS sed: `-e $'1i\\\ntext to add'`

Comment: how toadd variable value in sed command

Answer (score 44):

Echo is used to get the text. Cat filename - prints the file in the console and > uses it to send to another file filename1 and then we move filename1 to filename to get the text inserted to the first line of desired file.

```
  (echo "some text" && cat filename) > filename1 && mv filename1 filename
```

Comment: Please let me know why the following is downvoted

Comment: Perhaps because the OP mentions sed. That does not deserve a down vote in my opinion. That solution was even the best fitting my needs, then upvoted.

Comment: I upvoted.  works on ksh for me.

Comment: this is great solutions! it work in Makefile & MacOS well.

Comment: 1. Sed is installed _everywhere_
2. This is not an elegant solution : You call 1 builtin + cat + mv instead of just calling one command. Imagine the waste of time if this solution is used as part of a script that will run it thousands of time.

Comment: @binarym as what I know, `sed` is not globally working in sync *everywhere*, for example : some of `sed` command are not do-able in OSX, even tho the program name is called `sed`, some say installing `gnu-sed` will fix the problem, but that mean not using the tool that comes with the OS anymore, instead, using outsourcing tool, but again, the post creator asking for sed, that's probably the main reason this answer in not accepted as solution.

Answer (score 23):

You can use the POSIX tool `ex`:

```
ex a.txt <<eof
1 insert
Sunday
.
xit
eof
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Answer (score 16):

Using GNU awk >= 4.1:

```
awk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "first line"}{print}' foo.sh
```

In opposite to all the `sed` answers, this works on empty files too.

Comment: `inplace` is a library, and unfortunately it appears on all awk distributions ship it.  I get "awk: fatal: can't open source file 'inplace' for reading" `GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)`

Answer (score 9):

```
sed  -i '1i new_text' file_name
```

If you don't specify the `-i` option, it won't show any error, and displays the output on standard terminal, but doesn't insert the text in the file.

Comment: The question is not about the `-i` switch.

Comment: How do you figure that?  It ***is*** an answer to the question.  Yes, it's *similar* to the accepted answer, but not exactly the same.

Comment: @G-Man - one might argue the template used by cas is far from ideal but really, this is _similar_ like in _nearly identical_... the difference being the spacing and the fact this one has no backslash. As far as I am concerned they are technically identical (as they are both `gnu sed` specific and it just happens that `gnu sed` will accept the `i` without a backslash). If others think this warrants a separate answer + an upvote... oh well.

Answer (score 7):

You want to *insert* text before the first line rather than *append* it after, so use

```
sed '1 i\
your_text' your_file
```

A here document can also help:

```
cat /dev/stdin your_file <<EOI
Your text
goes here
EOI
```

Answer (score 5):

The `0a` command you attempted *does* work in [`ex`, the predecessor to `vi`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html):

```
printf '%s\n' 0a 'Anything you want to add' . x | ex file.txt
```

The `printf` command by itself outputs:

```
0a
Anything you want to add
.
x
```

The `0a` means append after the 0th line (i.e. before the first line).

The next line *or multiple lines* is literal text to be added.

The `.` on a line by itself terminates the "append" command.

The `x` causes Ex to save the changes to the file and exit.

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised that in this old question nobody has shown the most common (and quite simple in this case) sed command:

```
$ sed  -i '1s/^/new_text\
/' file_name
```

Which works in most shells and is portable to several sed versions, provided that the file contains at least one valid line.
If GNU sed is available, you may use this:

```
$ sed -i '1s/^/new_text\n' file_name
```

The difference is that GNU sed allow the use of a `\n` for a newline and others need a literal newline preceded by a backslash (which also work in GNU sed anyway).

If a shell which accepts the `$'…'` syntax is in use, you may insert the newline directly, so sed sees that the newline is already there:

```
$ sed -i $'1s/^/new_text\\\n/' file_name
```

Which works for more sed versions.

If the file has no lines (i.e: its empty) just:

```
$ echo "new_text" > file_name
```

Comment: What if there is no lines in the file?

Comment: @Justalearner The title of the question asks for: *insert text before the first line of a file*, so, a first line must already exist. That is also a problem for the selected answer.

Comment: Amazing answer @Isaac. This is certainly the only solution which works in the literal sense. I needed to add "schema": before the first line without any new line to be added.
Your solution work -> sed -i '1s/^/"schema":/' o

Answer (score 2):

I had issues with BSD sed (MacOS) and inserting text from a variable, so this is how I did it:

```
headers=a,b,c
sed -i '' -e "1{x;s/^.*/$headers/p;x;} some_file"
```

Explanation

- `1{...}` This affects only the first line
- `x` swap the current line with the hold space (currently empty)
- `s/../../p` replaces (the now empty line) with the expected text (this avoids the line-break problem) and outputs it (so the first line will be get printed)
- `x` swap again, retrieving the file first line which was in the hold space into the pattern space

Answer (score 2):

To insert text to the first line and put the rest on a new line using sed on macOS this worked for me

```bsh
sed -i '' '1 i \
Insert
' ~/Downloads/File-path.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, all the answers above (mostly with `sed`) didn't work out for me since they all substituted the first line. I am on an `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` machine. Here is my workaround with `GNU Awk 4.0.2`:

```
awk '{if(NR==1){$0="NEW_FIRST_LINE"$0; print $0} ;if(NR!=1){print $0}}' file_name
```

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about... There's only one `sed` answer that uses replacement but it doesn't substitute the existing line.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the text **hello** before the first line without a carriage return or line feed to the file **myfile**

```
sed -i '1s/^/hello /' myfile
```

This will also not output the entire file on the terminal.

Comment: perfect for appending spend 1 hour then got your solution

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e "task goes here\n$(cat todo.txt)" > todo.txt

echo "task goes here
$(cat todo.txt)" > todo.txt

echo 'task goes here'$'\n'"$(cat todo.txt)" > todo.txt
```

(https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested,  my problem was to insert same header line into several files. Thanks to proposed solution,  I came up with this :

```
sed -i 1i\ $(cat header_line) data.csv
```

where `header_line` is a file containing desired first line ,

Answer (score 0):

Just similar to Ankit Shah's answer:

```
(echo "some text" && cat filename) > /tmp/filename && cat /tmp/filename > filename
```

It's not convenient to use such a long command, so I create a simple bash function (in .bashrc or elsewhere possible) as following:

```
echo0 () {
  (echo ${@:2} && cat $1) > /tmp/$1
  cat /tmp/$1 > $1
}
# $1 is your-file-name, ${@:2} are contents after "your-file-name".
# How to use:
#   > echo0 myfile hellow world etc.
#   > head myfile
#     hellow world etc.
#     ...
```

Answer (score -2):

## `sed` can insert (multiple times) before the first and after the last

I would assume that anyone who searched for how to insert/append text to the beginning/end of a file probably also needs to know how to do the other also.

```
cal |                            \
  gsed -E                        \
       -e     '1i\{'             \
       -e     '1i\  "lines": ['  \
       -e 's/(.*)/    "\1",/'    \
       -e '$s/,$//'              \
       -e     '$a\  ]'           \
       -e     '$a\}'
```

### Explanation

This is `cal` output piped to gnu-`sed` (called `gsed` on macOS installed via [brew.sh](https://brew.sh)) with extended RegEx (`-E`) and 6 "scripts" applied (`-e`) and line breaks escaped with `\` for readability.

- Scripts 1 & 2 use `1i\` to "at line 1, insert".
- Scripts 5 & 6 use `$a\` to "at line <last>, append".

  - I vertically aligned the text outputs to make the code represent what is expected in the result.
- Scripts 3 & 4 do substitutions

  - Script 4 applies only to "line <last>" because of the `$` placed before the `s/`.

The result is converting command output to valid JSON.

#### output

```
{
  "lines": [
    "    October 2019      ",
    "Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  ",
    "       1  2  3  4  5  ",
    " 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  ",
    "13 14 15 16 17 18 19  ",
    "20 21 22 23 24 25 26  ",
    "27 28 29 30 31        ",
    "                      "
  ]
}
```

Comment: While I haven't voted on your question, note that we already have several answers, including an accepted one, that demonstrate the desired result.

Comment: @JeffSchaller The Stack Exchange community is not a forum. Its purpose extends beyond helping the OP get unblocked. The goal is to seed the global knowledge base with many options that seekers can stumble upon when searching for answers. The reason I titled my answer is to help users recognize the utility of this answer before they even click the Google result.

Comment: What I'm saying is that your answer isn't providing any *new* options (answers) for future readers of this question. We already have four answers that use variations of `1i` to insert text before the first line. Someone with this question would have to extract the parts they need from your answer in order to solve their problem. Questions are free, so I'd invite you to ask & answer your own question in order to provide your specific answer.