# Add a tab character to beginning of a file without a line return

Tags: sed

A very similar question has probably been asked many times, e.g. [How to insert text before the first line of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99350/how-to-insert-text-before-the-first-line-of-a-file)

But all those solutions add a tab, then a line return to the beginning of the file. I want to add just a tab to the start of the first line.. how to do that??

Thanks very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it, assuming a shell smart enough to know about `<(...)` construction, and an `echo` smart enough to know what to do with `-n` and `-e` options:

```
cat <(echo -ne '\t') file
```

Alternatively:

```
( printf '\t'; cat file ) >new_file
```

If you must do it with `sed`, assuming your `sed` is smart enough to know about `\t`:

```
sed '1s/^/\t/' file
```

But that's a lot more problematic, depending on the implementation of your `sed`.  It also doesn't work for empty files.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ex`, which is specified by POSIX.  Add a tab-newline sequence at the start of the file, then run `ex`'s `join` command.

This works whether the file is empty or not, and should be fully portable to any UNIX or Linux system.

(Note that if the file begins as an empty file, the contents after this command will be a tab character *and* a newline.  A file without a terminating newline is technically not actually a text file.)

```
printf '0a\n\t\n.\n1j!\nx\n' | ex myfile.txt
```

If you run the `printf` command by itself you can see the instructions that are getting passed to `ex`:

```
$ printf '0a\n\t\n.\n1j!\nx\n'
0a

.
1j!
x
```

Note that there is a single tab character in the otherwise blank line above.

Answer (score -1):

```
sed '1 s/^/\t/' < textfile.txt
```