# Prepend a string of characters at the beginning of all files in a given directory

Tags: bash, text-processing

I would like to add login credentials

```
user: XXX ; pass:YYYY
```

as text line in all files of a given directory (as a string at the start of each file).

Also i would like to add this only in files with a certain extension `.kkk`

How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert text before the first line of a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99350/how-to-insert-text-before-the-first-line-of-a-file)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` or `awk` for that:

- `sed`:

  ```
  sed '1i\user: XXX ; pass:YYY' *.kkk
  ```
- `awk`:

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN{print "user: XXX ; pass:YYY"}1' *.kkk
  ```

In order to edit the files in-place, use the `-i` option for `sed`. For `awk` this only works since GNU `awk` version 4.1, when using the `-i inplace` option.

Update: This question has already answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28116144/12231187) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99350/377345) (and possibly others).