How to insert text before the first line of an UTF-8 with BOM file
This question is closely related to: How to insert text before the first line of a file?. I deliberately made the title similar to that question to highlight this.
Except the target file is UTF-8 with BOM.
So, I want to add a first line to a file that has UTF-8 BOM bytes at its heading (0xef 0xbb 0xbf characters). At least the UTF-8 with BOM files I have here begin with this.
If I just go ahead and follow the solutions in the related question,
sed "1i My First line is now this." file.txt

I will get (in VSCode in my case) something like
My First line is now this.
?The first line was this one
Second line and so on

Being ? in the second line the UTF-8 character to express something non-printable.
Another consequence, as one would expect, is the file no longer opens as UTF-8 with BOM and we rely on the text editor features to "guess" its encoding now. We have determined a pattern in our project to have files with BOM to ensure everything is in the same encoding.
How do I preserve the BOM header in the file while adding the text?

From the very same related question, one answer opens door to the solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/455250/413756
Then with a little regex select-groups tinkering, I came up with this expression:
sed -Ei "1s/^(|\xef\xbb\xbf)/\1My First line is now this.\n/" file.txt

And i got the desired result, preserving the UTF-8 BOM header in the file and even making the replacement in files that eventually won't match the header.
If you're sure all files are BOM, then this should be enough:
sed -Ei "1s/^(\xef\xbb\xbf)/\1My First line is now this.\n/" file.txt

Notice this catches specificly UTF-8 BOM files with the exact same header I have here. I believe different byte sequences might happen to different formats which is up to each case -- and probably possible with the above regex (just add/replace |\xXX\xYY\xZZ or corresponding match to the select group).
Notice also in both replacements I'm assuming files' line ending is just \n (unix LF), not \r\n (windows CRLF).
The above syntax worked on GNU Sed (Cygwin and probably most Linux distributions).

UTF-8 BOM is very non-Unix, it's most likely coming from the Microsoft world. Then line ending will also likely be CRLF rather than LF and there may even be more Microsoft idiosyncrasies to deal with. If you want to process those with Unix/GNU tools, you're probably better of doing:
dos2unix -- "$file" &&
  sed -i -e '1i\
new line' -- "$file" &&
  unix2dos -m -- "$file"

For in-place editing (here using GNU style -in-place editing) or:
{
  echo new line
  <"$file" dos2unix
} | unix2dos -m > "$newfile"

To process on the fly (here without the need for sed) and have the result stored (back in Microsoft format with BOM) in the new file.
Another approach is to use perl (where some sed implementations have copied their -i option from), and use the File::BOM module as an IO layer in addition to the :crlf IO layer to deal with Microsoft line endings:
perl -MFile::BOM '-Mopen=IO,:crlf:via(File::BOM)' -pi -E '
  say "new line" if $. == 1' your-file

Example:
$ printf '£%s\n' {1..5} | unix2dos -m > msdos-utf-8-with-bom
$ sed -n l msdos-utf-8-with-bom
\357\273\277\302\2431\r$
\302\2432\r$
\302\2433\r$
\302\2434\r$
\302\2435\r$
$ perl -MFile::BOM '-Mopen=IO,:crlf:via(File::BOM)' -pi -E 'say "new line" if $. == 1' msdos-utf-8-with-bom
$ sed -n l msdos-utf-8-with-bom
\357\273\277new line\r$
\302\2431\r$
\302\2432\r$
\302\2433\r$
\302\2434\r$
\302\2435\r$

See the BOM moved to the start of the new line and the first line also delimited with CRLF.
One approach to be able to cope with files that can have either Microsoft or Unix line ending and either a UTF-8 BOM or not, you could do something like:
perl -pi -se 's/^(?:\xef\xbb\xbf)?\K.*?(\r?)$/$new$1\n$&/ if $. == 1
  ' -- -new='new line' file

Where, on the first line ($. == 1), we Keep the BOM if any, and then insert the newline followed by a \r if it was found at the end of the first line, then \n, then the original first line.
That doesn't insert the new line if the file was initially empty (without BOM) but then wouldn't know whether to add the new line with a Microsoft or Unix line ending.

The BOM shouldn't have anything to do with Windows or line ending; it's just an Unicode thing, that is, related to character sets and encoding of the text stream; be it a file or a string, right? In my particular case, the text files are UTF-8 with BOM and LF line endings. Your approach to preserve the line ending in the other hand is a great plus to the solution. I was just lazy to draw that in my solution as it was a bit outside the focus of the question.

I've never seen a UTF-8 BOM (which makes no sense and goes in the way of everything) on any system other than Microsoft ones. I can't image a Unix software using a BOM in UTF-8 other than to interact with Microsoft software, or them being ports of proprietary Windows software to Unix. In particular, it gets in the way of text processing pipelines and none of the standard POSIX utilities deal with UTF-8 BOM and you need to remove it first before being able to do anything with those.

I couldn't agree more with your statements. As a matter of fact, this is a case where I needed to interact with an Windows project tracked by git DVCS. The code was supposed to keep these headers so that developers' IDEs wouldn't switch them to other strange encodings.
